# After Database and LINQ optimisations, web app is overloading CPU. Can I make SQL Server run slower?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, sql-server-2017

We optimised our databases by indexing and using more efficient LINQ statements. Now, the web app is overloading the CPU.
It is written very inefficiently with nested iterations getting data mostly from a cache store. We think that the slower database retrieval times kept a throttle on the system.

Is there a way to make retrieval times slower so that we can save the CPU? There were many hundreds of improvements made that would be too complex to role back. Can we strangle the bandwidth or changes SQL Server settings ?

***Update*** We use Amazon RDS which doesn't allow changes to memory or parallelism.

I can't reduce memory or CPUs, so.. would I get a tempering effect if I ran some traces on the SQL Server? At 40K statements a minute, it could be costly enough to slow results to the web app?

Another option could be to run a pointless statement in a loop from the query window. Can anyone suggest something safe that would slow things down across the board?

Things get heated daily at about 6pm for 3 hours.

RDS Restrictions:

> • AlwaysOn AG* • Stretch Database • Buffer Pool Extension • BULK
>   INSERT and OPENROWSET(BULK…) features • Data Quality Services •
>   Database Log Shipping • Database Mail • Distributed Queries(Linked
>   Servers)* • Distributed Transaction Coordinator(MSDTC) • File Tables •
>   FILESTREAM Support • Maintenance Plans • Performance Data Collector •
>   Policy-Based Management • Polybase • R • Replication • Resource
>   Governor • SQL Server Audit • Server-level triggers • Service Broker
>   endpoints • T-SQL endpoints (all operations using CREATE ENDPOINTs are
>   unavailable) • WCF Data Services • SSAS, SSRS, SSIS • Master Data
>   Services

Comment: One of my suggestion - If you are using SP and calling functions in where condition then convert that function in the view and join with the query.

Comment: No. The database requests are all screamingly fast and efficient. The small number of SPs are written correctly. It is the web application processing that is the issue.

Comment: Even if your conclusion is wrong, you CAN "make retrieval times slower". Add waitfor delay to your code and it will wait as much as you want

Comment: @sepupic There are very few SPs. It is mostly LINQ and thousands of LINQ methods.

Comment: I only said that your approach is wrong: "make retrieval times slower so that we can save the CPU". You should find what is slowing down your CPU and rewrite that part, not to "make retrieval times slower"

Comment: @sepupic The behemoth of a system could be using CPU evenly across dozens of poorly written processes. I don't think we can target anything and multiple code changes will require rebuilds. I'd prefer it if we could make every single request to the database to have a small delay. We have 40K statements a minute, nearly all at zero duration. If I could make them all 1ms..

Comment: If you don't want to change your code, limit your server memory to some small value so that every time server would read from disk, this of course will slow down the response time

Comment: @sepupic That sounds plausible, but it is either reading from disk or not, so there might be a sudden threshold when the db can't cope, which we can't risk. Can you think of any other options?

Comment: You can limit your SQL Server to use only one core, so your queries would be always serial, slow, and CPU will work only for your app

Comment: @sepupic Thanks, but I failed to mention that we run on Amazon RDS, which doesn't let us change parallelism.

Comment: @sepupic Arggh! or memory. We cannot reduce form 7991MB. It is fixed! I have updated the OP.

Comment: *I can't reduce memory or CPUs* Which means that you can't run [Sql Server Resource Governor](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6081/sql-server-resource-governor-configuration-with-tsql-and-ssms/) statements either?

Comment: @GertArnold Unfortunately, not. I am updating the OP with a list of RDS restrictions.

Comment: You have a web application that is badly written, but instead of fixing the problem with the web application, you want to throttle the database?

Comment: @robbpriestley Yes. It is a busy web-retail business coming up to Christmas. The app is enormous and suffers from legacy problems. Putting a throttle on is our best bet.

Comment: @cloudsafe the busiest e-commerce day is usually Cyber Monday, which is already over. If you made it through that day, you may be ok. It may be just me but the idea of throttling a database sounds like a risk onto itself.

Comment: @robbpriestley We sell vouchers to be redeemed, which is done in the days following our sales. We have busy sales and redeeming, still. The throttling is the best method I can think of to reduce the speed evenly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could migrate the RDS database to a smaller instance. So, for example if you are on a **db.t3.medium**, you could migrate to a **db.t3.small**, which has less CPU and RAM.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/instance-types/

Of course, you'd need to work out a migration strategy in order to be able to do that. Shouldn't be too difficult except for maybe a gap during cutover.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. I'll run it past technical.

Comment: Yes. It seems that might be our best option.